# How to change an object property passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, parameters

I want to pass an object to a method, however during this I want to change a property of said object. The way I do it now is like this:

```
MyClass someClass= someClasses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Propert1. == "1");
someClass.Property1 = 2;
MyMethod(someClass);
```

However I dont want to do the extra step of creating a variable and then setting the property.

```
MyMethod(someClasses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Propert1. == "1")/*.ChangeProperty()?*/); //This is where I would like to change Property1's value.
```

Is this good practice, if at all possible?

Comment: Is doing the extra step really causing you a problem..?

Comment: No it's not causing a problem, it resolves the problem, but I want the code to be in one line instead of 3.

Comment: I'd argue that you really want 3 lines, as compressing it down to 1 lines makes it hard to read and understand.

Comment: I think in this case that 3 lines of code will be easier to understand rather than a single line. Why do you only want one line of code?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The first example looks much more clear and easy to understand then the second. I'd stay with the first one.

Comment: Alright, but is it possible to do it in one line (as in is there a syntax to achieve this goal).

Comment: if you check any of the coding standards practice it will suggest you that you have to write code that is easy to maintain and easy to understand to you and other as well

Comment: Why? Readability is king and the extra line costs you nothing. You can do it on one line, but honestly it'll just make the code a bigger pain to read. 
Most companies put the extra methods, even if they are linked, on a seperate line anyway for readability. So it'll work, but it's not really better in my opinion

Comment: No -- good practice, if you really wanted this as a common style, would be making the object immutable, and then a fluent call like `?.WithProperty1(2)` makes more sense. As it stands, with a mutable object it's a good thing that you can clearly see the object is getting changed before being passed off to a call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason to do this on a single line. This code looks absolutely fine:

```
MyClass someClass= someClasses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Propert1. == "1");
someClass.Property1 = 2;
MyMethod(someClass);
```

If you want, you could add an extension method that does this:

```
// put this in a static class
static T WithNewPropertyValue<T>(this T t, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
    action(t);
    return t;
}
```

And call it like this

```
MyMethod(someClasses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Propert1 == "1").WithNewPropertyValue(x => x.Propert1 = "2"));
```

But I feel like this decreases the readability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the extension method which changes a property *and returns changed object*:

```
public static MyClass WithProperty2(this MyClass source, int value)
{
   if (source != null)  // make sure you handle null
     source.Property2 = value;

   return source;
}
```

Now you have a fluent API to do one-liners (which does not make your code much more maintainable):

```
MyMethod(someClasses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Propert1. == "1").WithProperty2(42))
```